# Add event listener on element focus

Tags: javascript

I have a search box input that opens when an icon is clicked on. I would like to give the input focus when the icon is clicked and call the function addLabel() that adds a label as placeholder text until a “onkeydown” event is fired, at which time it should call the function removeLabel(). Currently, my script adds focus(), but doesn’t acknowledge the other event listeners. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
window.onload = function() {

<!-- create absolutly positioned label as placeholder text for search -->
        var el = document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1');
        var label = document.createElement('label');
        var labelText = document.createTextNode('Enter your search term...');
        label.appendChild(labelText);
        label.className += 'search-label-placeholder';
        var searchParent = el.parentNode;
        searchParent.insertBefore(label, el);

        var searchIcon = document.getElementById('search-icon');
        searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            el.addEventListener('focus', addLabel );
            el.addEventListener('keydown', removeLabel );
            el.focus();
        }, false );

           function removeLabel() {

            el.style.textIndent = '0';
            el.setAttribute('placeholder', 'removeLabel');
            el.style.background = 'none';
            el.style.textIndent = '0';
            label.style.display = 'none';
           };
           function addLabel() {

            el.style.textIndent = '0';
            el.setAttribute('placeholder', 'addLabel');
            el.style.background = 'none';
            el.style.textIndent = '0';
            label.style.display = 'block';
            };
        };
```

```html
<div class="header-holder">
     <!-- header logotype -->
     <strong class="header-logo">
                <a href="/"><img alt="Rose-Hulman Institute of Technology" src="../../../assets/images/logo-header.svg"></a>
            </strong>
     <!-- header actions -->
     <ul class="header-actions">
      <li>
       <button class="header-actions-btn header-actions-btn-search" data-action="search" id="search-icon">
        <span class="icon icon-search"><span class="hide-for-screen-reader">Search</span></span>
       </button>
      </li>
      <li>
       <button class="header-actions-btn header-actions-btn-menu" data-action="menu">
        <span class="icon icon-menu"><span class="hide-for-screen-reader">Menu</span></span>
       </button>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <!-- header search form -->
     <div class="header-search">
      <div id="___gcse_0">
       <div class="gsc-control-searchbox-only gsc-control-searchbox-only-en" dir="ltr">
        <form class="gsc-search-box gsc-search-box-tools" accept-charset="utf-8">
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gsc-search-box">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="gsc-input">
             <div class="gsc-input-box" id="gsc-iw-id1">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="gs_id50" class="gstl_50 " style="width: 100%; padding: 0px;">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                 <td id="gs_tti50" class="gsib_a">
                  <label class="search-label-placeholder" style="display: none;">Enter your search term...</label>
                  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" size="10" class="gsc-input" name="search" title="search" id="gsc-i-id1" x-webkit-speech="" x-webkit-grammar="builtin:search" lang="en" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" placeholder="removeLabel" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: 0px; height: auto; outline: none; background: none left center no-repeat rgb(255, 255, 255); text-indent: 0px;">
                 </td>
                 <td class="gsib_b">
                  <div class="gsst_b" id="gs_st50" dir="ltr"><a class="gsst_a" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"><span class="gscb_a" id="gs_cb50">×</span></a></div>
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
             <input type="hidden" name="bgresponse" id="bgresponse">
            </td>
            <td class="gsc-search-button">
             <input type="image" src="https://www.google.com/uds/css/v2/search_box_icon.png" class="gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2" title="search">
            </td>
            <td class="gsc-clear-button">
             <div class="gsc-clear-button" title="clear results">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gsc-branding">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="gsc-branding-user-defined"></td>
            <td class="gsc-branding-text">
             <div class="gsc-branding-text">powered by</div>
            </td>
            <td class="gsc-branding-img"><img src="https://www.google.com/cse/static/images/1x/googlelogo_grey_46x15dp.png" class="gsc-branding-img" srcset="https://www.google.com/cse/static/images/2x/googlelogo_grey_46x15dp.png 2x"></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a complete (runnable) example. This means in your case, adding the HTML markup too.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I've added the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your code if fine. Workable fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/0j3rom2m/

Check input element in the dom - it has 'removeLabel' placeholder as you start typing.

SO wants some code when you link to fiddle, so:

```
searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('clicked');
  el.addEventListener('focus', addLabel );
  el.addEventListener('keydown', removeLabel );
  el.focus();
}, false );
```